# Using QGIS and Python to develop sound attenuation model?

Tags: pyqgis, model

I am in the process of developing a model that allows me to see sound attenuation over distance from a point source. I am using this [sound attenuation equation](http://www.mne.psu.edu/lamancusa/me458/10_osp.pdf):

Lp = Lw - 20logr - 11 - Aabs - Ae

where Lp = sound pressure (dB); Lw = sound pressure at point source (db); r = radius from source (m); Aabs = atmospheric absorption; Ae = excess attenuation (vegetation, barriers...)

I have a DSM over flat ground that I would like to apply this model to, it has open grassland, vegetation and houses. I will use conditionals to insert the appropriate variable for the surface type.

Is there a simple way to apply the equation to each pixel in a raster from the point source, iterating out radially (not spirally) instead of in a loop? As I am using the DSM, the newly generated value is directly dependent on the previous db(A) value in the line of sight from source. I should create a new value for each pixel until I reach background noise levels - this new data can be used to create and overlay a noise map on to a basemap.

If the approach seems way off, please be critical -- up until now I assumed that I should be looking for a way to apply this equation to a NumPy array; perhaps this is also an inefficient methodology? (Python newbie!)

Comment: I think the problem is that as you go further from the source your radial points will be too spaced out, and to fill in the gaps you have to do a whole new radius. You probably end up evaluating more points than if you just did a whole grid. I don't know if numpy has some fast line-drawing algorithms that will let you sample pixels on a line, but that's what you need... Could possibly be speeded up x1000 with GPU code....

Comment: I don't know why I was so convinced I had to do this radially. I can simply calculate each point based on it's distance and the obstacles directly in line with chosen pixel and point source.

As of yet I have no idea how to script this, but at least I don't have to worry about the initial issue anymore!